# Using TTask::Future<> in Embarcadero XE7 C++

Tags: c++, multithreading

I tried to make "Tutorial: Using Futures from the Parallel Programming Library" from [here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/Tutorial:_Using_Futures_from_the_Parallel_Programming_Library). 
I created project "File > New > Multi-Device Application - C++Builder > Blank Application" and copy source from link.

```
#include <System.Threading.hpp>
```

**.h**

```
public:     // User declarations
    System::DelphiInterface<IFuture__1<System::String> > FutureString;
    System::String __fastcall FutureHandler(TObject* Sender);
```

**.cpp**

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender) {
   FutureString = TTask::Future<System::String>(0, this->FutureHandler);
}

System::String __fastcall TForm1::FutureHandler(TObject* Sender) {
  Sleep(3000);
  System::String str = System::String().sprintf(L"Hello %d", Random(42));
  return str;
}
```

After build I'm getting this error message:

> [ilink64 Error] Error: Unresolved external 'System::DelphiInterface > System::Threading::TTask::Future(System::TObject*, System::UnicodeString (* __closure)(System::TObject*))' referenced from C:\USERS\PC\DESKTOP\64BIT\WIN64\DEBUG\UNIT1.O

declaration from **System.Threading.hpp**

```
 template<typename T> static System::DelphiInterface<IFuture__1<T> >
   __fastcall Future(System::TObject* Sender, T __fastcall (__closure *)
    (System::TObject* Sender) )/* overload */;
```

**===**

```
protected:
HIDESBASE System::DelphiInterface<IFuture__1<T> > __fastcall Start(void);
T __fastcall GetValue(void);
#ifndef _WIN64
typedef T __fastcall (__closure *_dt_System_Threading_2)(System::TObject* Sender);
__fastcall TFuture__1(System::TObject* Sender, _dt_System_Threading_2 Event, 
const System::DelphiInterface<System::Sysutils::TFunc__1<T> > Func, TThreadPool* APool)/* overload */;
#else /* _WIN64 */
__fastcall TFuture__1(System::TObject* Sender, TFunctionEvent__1<T> Event, const System::DelphiInterface<System::Sysutils::TFunc__1<T> > Func, TThreadPool* 
APool)/* overload */;
#endif /* _WIN64 */

private:
 // __classmethod void __fastcall Destroy@();
protected:
/* TTask.Create */ inline __fastcall TFuture__1(System::TObject* Sender, 
System::Classes::TNotifyEvent Event, const System::Sysutils::_di_TProc AProc, TThreadPool* const APool, TTask* const AParent, TTask::TCreateFlags CreateFlags)/* overload */ : TTask(Sender, Event, AProc, APool, AParent, CreateFlags) { }

public:
/* TTask.Create */ inline __fastcall TFuture__1(void)/* overload */ : 
TTask() { }
/* TTask.Destroy */ inline __fastcall virtual ~TFuture__1(void) { }

private:
void *__IFuture__1; // IFuture__1<T> 

public:
operator IFuture__1<T>*(void) { return (IFuture__1<T>*)&__IFuture__1; }

};
```

how to cope with this error?